# how to/can we add two tables having nothing common in between them in crystal report for C# wnidows form application

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUJD1.png)I'm working on sap crystal report 2013 for C# windows application.
I want to add two tables on the report.As I know I can use data-set for it. But these two tables don't have any common data value between them.
So is there any way to sort out this problem.
two tables I'm using are  1. SocietyInfo & 2.VisitorInfo
I'm doing report for all info. about visitors. While doing this I've taken another table societyInfo on this report. but at the of preview its only show single table information. it doesn't display societyInfo's record.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzU6t.png)

Comment: So what is your intent, if the two tables have nothing in common? What do you want to do??

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I just want to know is it possible ?? If yes then how. whats the solution?

Comment: Almost everything is possible, but you haven't stated so far, what and how you want to see in report.

Comment: I'm doing project regarding society management. so on the report for example- visitor Info.  on one header I want to show society info. & on details page I want to display visitor Info.

Comment: How are societies and visitors related? Provide sample data and output.

Comment: nope they are not related thats the point. society info contains society name,address & Reg.No.  Visitor Info contains all personal data  about visitor..so they are very different form each oyher

Comment: Sample output please, edit main question, not in comments. For two societies and two visitors would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to your 'enter image description here' :) the simplest way is to insert subreport into report header and use you societies table in subreport, not in main report. You don't need to link main- and subreport in any way.